# how can I make a mobile robot as ros enabled?

Tags: ros, robot, mobile

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS. In my university there is a  mobile manipulator,which have no ROS support. I like to implement path planning using ROS on this. Is it possible to do that? I am very sorry if my question is childish.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/240656/how-can-i-make-a-mobile-robot-as-ros-enabled?/) by [sreeji](https://answers.ros.org/users/27633/sreeji/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you can do that with ROS.
But there is no way to get around having to learn ROS first. You will need to start at the beginning and go through the ROS tutorials.

Start at the top of this page and work you way down, drilling into the links: http://wiki.ros.org/

Once you've learned the basic about how it works, you will start to have specific questions you can ask here.
It's not a 30 minute exercise to get started. It will require many hours to get started.
Good luck.

---

Originally posted by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) with karma: 1850 on 2016-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0